# I have suddenly lost the ability to transmit CW on M IC-7200 xnxceiver. I am able to receive sigs but keyer does not work.makes dits but no dahs

Tags: cw, icom, paddles

My trusty IC-7200 has worked flawlessly for over 15 years but now I can't transit CW which is the only mode I work. I think something in the set for paddle connection is wrong.

The directions in my iCom-7200 manual are confusing to me. Could someone step me through this process!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found the answer already but just in case you did not, here goes...

On page 18 of the Icom 7200 manual, it explains how to set the Key Type. You did not specify what type of key you use (paddle or straight key) but the setting may not be correct. I would suggest you go into the menu settings (SET MODE) and find the entry for KEY TYPE. It will be either bG or St. If you are using a paddle, set it to bG. If you are using a straight key, set it to St. Also confirm the KEY PoL menu is set to n for Normal.